# How to get sidebar widgets in leftsidebar template

Tags: widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I have created a custom sidebar widgets using below code :

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => 'sidebar-widget-1',
        'name' => 'Sidebar Widget 1',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',

    ));
```

and it is showing in `Appearance -> Widgets` and it is also showing content on frontend using `dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Widget 1')`.

But I want to get content of this `register_sidebar` by using its `id` into a variable.

How to get sidebar content by using its `id`?

Answer (score 0):

In your sidebar.php or any other custom sidebar file call by ID like this

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-widget-1'); ?>
```

Not like this

```
<?php get_sidebar('Sidebar Widget 1'); ?>
```

See the difference, I used ID in `get_sidebar()` function instead of name.

Now where ever you want sidebar appear in front-end, there call it like this

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-widget-1'); ?>
```

Comment: Hello @Rishabh, I want to get sidebar content one by one with all options in a variable.

Comment: @Vinaya Maheshwari Sorry, Didn't get your point. What u mean by one by one and options of what variable?

Answer (score 0):

From your question you have already registered the sidebar.

To get the content of the sidebar into a variable, i think you can use php buffering :

```php
   // ob_start - Turn on output buffering
   // ob_get_contents - Return the contents of the output buffer
   // ob_end_clean - Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
```

Such as this :

```php
   // Turn on output buffering
   ob_start();
   // Specify the sidebar using its [id]
   dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-widget-1');
   // Store the return contents of the output buffer in a variable
   // in this case $sidebar_content
   $sidebar_content = ob_get_contents();
   // Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
   ob_end_clean();
```

if you need to get more than one sidebar content, like you need the get the content of several sidebars at once then you can:

```php
    // Get the list of all registered sidebars using wp_registered_sidebars
    foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) :
        // Turn on output buffering
        ob_start();
        // This will get all the sidebars
        dynamic_sidebar($sidebar['id']);
        // Store the return contents of the output buffer in a variable
        // in this case $sidebars_content
        $sidebars_content = ob_get_contents();
        // Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
        ob_end_clean();
    endif;
```

OR

```php
    // Get the global registered sidebars
    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
    // Loop through each content in $wp_registered_sidebars array
    foreach($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar_id => $sidebar) :
        ob_start();
        // This will get all the sidebars
        dynamic_sidebar($sidebar['id']);
        // Store the return contents of the output buffer in a variable
        // in this case $sidebars_content
        $sidebars_content = ob_get_contents();
        // Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
        ob_end_clean();
    endforeach;
```

Hope one on this helps you.